# Запись текста в файл в дизайнере форм

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Ребят, хотел переделать код. Вместо &File.AppendAllText хотел сделать добавление текста в файл через Append, Reset и т.д. Подскажите, что я не так добавил? Ошибка:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на
> экземпляр объекта.

Код

```
procedure Form2.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var F:textfile;
begin
 Assign(F,'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
 Reset(F);
 writeln(F, textBox1.Text);
 writeln(F, textBox2.Text + #13#10);
 textBox1.Clear;
 textBox2.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: Один из используемых объектов не создан (`textBox1` или `textBox2`). В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Текстбоксы созданы в дизайнере, ошибка на writeln(F, textBox1.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо Assign написать AssignFile

---

**UPD**
Вспомнил, чтобы фокус удался, надо не Reset(F), а Append(F) использовать! После этого метод WriteLn будет добавлять строчки в конец файла. Другими словами, ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
procedure Form2.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var
   F:textfile;
begin
 AssignFile(F,'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
 Append(F);
 writeln(F, textBox1.Text);
 writeln(F, textBox2.Text + #13#10);
 textBox1.Clear;
 textBox2.Clear;
 CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Самое главное -  не забывайте после окончания работы с текстовым файлом закрывать его **CloseFile()**, иначе у вас возникнут проблемы с сохранением последних внесенных изменений в файл.

**Append()** - открывает файл для записи и устанавливает курсор в конец файла.
**ReWrite()**  - если файла нет, то создает его. Если файл есть, то открывает его для записи, чистит содержимое, и устанавливает курсор в начало.
**Reset()** открывает файл для чтения и устанавливает курсор на начало файла.

Comment: Всеравно выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: хорошо, тогда вместо Reset(F) сделайте Rewrite(F);  
Проверьте, будет работать?

Comment: @teanЫЧ сама кнопка нажимается, не вылетает. Но информация не записывается в файл

Comment: @Sin2p, может быть потому что у вас нет Close(F)?

Comment: @teanЫЧ Отлично, все работает. Поиск по файлу идет. Но теперь вопрос: когда я просматриваю фаил через текстбокс, вместо имени - вопр.зн. Как исправить?

Comment: @Sin2p,  
обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

У Вашей программы есть права на создание файла на рабочем столе? Попробуйте создать файл в другом месте.

```
AssignFile(F, 'D:\nomer.txt');
```

Comment: Все равно ошибка. Самое интересное - через &File.AppendAllText работает а через AppendFile не хочет

Comment: какой еще AppendFile?

Comment: ой, AssignFile, простите